# Have problem with webpack autoprefixer , didn`t add -webkit- to animation css?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a problem. I can not add some prefixes '-webkit' to animations css and other. But to flex are added -'ms'. Maybe the problem is in the list of browsers,

```
const autoprefixerOptions = {
    browsers:["Android 2.3", "Android >= 4", "Chrome >= 20", "Firefox >= 24", "Explorer >= 8", "iOS >= 6", "Opera >= 12", "Safari >= 6"],
    grid: true
};

{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {loader: 'css-loader', options: {importLoaders: 2}},
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            ident: 'postcss',
                            plugins: [
                                require('autoprefixer')(autoprefixerOptions),
                                require('cssnano')()
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {loader: "sass-loader", options: {}}
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ordering the code, it will be more readable. For me, this solution generates a-webkit prefixer.

```
{
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
  sourceMap: true,
  config: {
    path: './config/',
  },
 },
},
```

In the "config" folder, I have the files postcss.config.js and webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
     'autoprefixer': {  },
     'postcss-url': {
       url: 'inline',
       maxSize: 50
     },
     'cssnano': {
       safe: true
     }
  }
};
```

The entire configuration of the autoprefixer is in the package.json file

```
"browserslist": [
  "last 2 version",
  "> 1%",
  "maintained node versions",
  "not dead"
],
```

Take a look at my project and see how it's solved - [github](https://github.com/tomik23/photoBlog).